# User submissions from mozilla full of random line breaks

Tags: php, sql, firefox, line-breaks

I've been building a site where users submit a logline and a synopsis for something. This works through a  that is then submitted using $_POST, and an SQL query is used to put it into an SQL table.  For some reason, ONLY IN MOZILLA FIREFOX (I've tested in chrome, IE, safari, and even on an ipad (Safari again)), by the time it gets to the SQL table it is full of random line breaks.  When  the submission is viewed on a different part of the site, no matter what the line breaks are there, so it is definitely a problem with Mozilla with the submission step.

So what is the issue with Mozilla?  I would love any help on making this not happen, here is what is being submitted (abridged to include relevant pieces):

User enters value in this kind of a textarea:

```
<form id="submitform" name="submitform" action="submit.php" onsubmit="return validateSubmitForm(event)" method="post">

    // some code

        <textarea style="height:300px;width:800px;font-family:Arial;border:1px solid #a6a6a6;
                         background-color:#fff9eb;resize:none" 
                  wrap="hard" size="1500" placeholder="1500 character limit..." maxlength="1500"
                  id="submitsummary" name="submitsummary" type="text"></textarea>

    // some code

</form>
```

Then, after the form is submitted as a $_POST, I input it into the data table with basically this SQL query:

```
"INSERT INTO table (userid, header, synopsis) 
VALUES(1, 1, " . htmlspecialchars($_POST["submitsummary"]) . ")"
```

Any thoughts on why it is that only Mozilla is being problematic?  Also, any thoughts on how to get around it?  Much appreciated!

Comment: not really on-topic, but please use prepared statements. You are vulnerable for sql injections with the query you provide.

Comment: @John Thanks for letting me know, this is my first coding so while I know what injections are I'm not really familiar with best ways to prevent them.  Any tips?

Comment: as a quick fix you can use: mysql_real_escape_string( htmlspecialchars($_POST["submitsummary"])). On the longer run, take a look at PDO or mysqli with prepared statements.

Comment: Just look up sql injection on Wikipedia for a quick overview. It's essentially where you aren't verifying that the entered data is properly escaped and free of evil intentions. I could enter "'); drop table users --". So I close off your query, try to drop your table and comment out the rest of your query. Prepared statements take placeholders for the variables and then when you set them, the framework will escape them for you.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully mysql_real_escape_string() won't cause any more format issues (I've been checking across browsers and the number of little things is driving me crazy...).  I'll definitely put that in there anywhere I have an SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wrap="hard"` is known to have issues with Firefox. Remove that and check if the random line breaks disappear.

Also set the `cols and rows attributes` for the textbox as Firefox also uses this to determine proper wrapping.

Comment: I removed wrap="hard" and it seems to have done the trick.  Thanks so much!

Comment: If by "issues" you mean "it's implemented the way the spec says it should be", then I suppose... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your issue is wrap="hard". This requires you to use the cols attribute and it inserts newlines at the wrap points of text in the textarea.

Removing the wrap or setting wrap="soft" will result in the submitted data only having newlines where the user hit enter (or if the user pasted, only where the pasted data had newlines).